# TypeLoadException from log4net LogManager.GetLogger

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, log4net, windows-ce

I'm attempting to use log4net to provide logging in a Windows CE/Windows Embedded project. However, when debugging the project I get the following exception

> System.TypeLoadException occurred
>     Message="TypeLoadException"
>     StackTrace:
>          at log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(Assembly repositoryAssembly, String name)
>          at log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(Type type)
>          at Sis.SiLogCE.Broker.StartBroker..cctor()
>          at Sis.SiLogCE.Broker.EntryPoint.Program.Main()

from the following line:

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(StartBroker));
```

At first, I thought I might have been using the wrong dll/an old dll so I downloaded the most recent version - I am using the log4net.dll from `1.2.12-bin-newkey` and found in .net-cp 3.5.

I've looked though other examples and though the documentation and I can see no reason why I'm getting a type load exception here. I'm now pretty much out of ideas as to what couple be causing the exception.

***Background information:***

Application is to be deployed on Windows CE 6 and Windows Embedded/Windows Mobile 6 and 6/5 devices.

.net 3.5
.netcf

The following block shows loading the config for log4net from an XML file named "log4net.config".

```
    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().
        GetModules()[0].FullyQualifiedName) + "log4net.config";

    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(path));
    }
```

EDITS:

Up until now, I've only tested on Wince 6.0 so I've just had a shot with Windows Mobile 6.5 - it's no different, the same exception is presented.

Comment: What is the inner exception?

Comment: @sgmoore - unfortunately, there isn't one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the binary release, or have you built from source ? I ask as [this](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/features.html) page mentions that Compact Framework 1.0 & 2.0 are ***not*** supported by the binary release, but are supported if built from the source release.

Comment: I was just reading that page - thanks for posting. Alas, now have a .net cf build. *Facepalm* Silly mistake that was staring me in the face. TY.